# How to create a list of variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I’m trying to create something like an inventory in ruby, so I can compare "params" against every line in that inventory, but I’m new to the language and I don’t know what might be the best way to do it.

Actually my code looks like this:

```
def parseParams(params)
    max_length = "xxxxxxxxxxx".length
    min_length = 2 #c1 for example

    if (params.length == 0)
        puts "[-] No parameters provided"
        return false
    elsif (params.length > max_length)
        puts "[-] The parameters are too long/invalid"
        return false
    elsif (params.length < min_length)
        puts "[-] The parameters are too short/invalid"
        return false
    else
        if (params == "c1" || params == "c2" || params == "c3")
            puts "[+] Valid parameters"
        return true
        end
    end
end
```

What I want to do is simplify the code and just verify whether "params" exists in this inventory, otherwise, return error.

Someone knows how to do it?, thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I can compare 'params' against every line in that inventory"* -- What is `inventory`? How do you want to "compare" it? What do you mean by "justify whether [something] *exists* in the inventory"?

Comment: For example inventory.txt and compare line by line, against param @TomLord

Comment: I don't understand what your current code is trying to do. You're saying there are only three valid inputs: `"c1"`, `"c2"` and `"c3"`. Why are those the only three valid inputs? If there are other valid inputs, then how can we determine them?

Comment: for example, c[1..10]r[1..10]s[1..10]

Comment: I just wanna create a file or something similar, put all valid inputs and then check against params

Comment: Are you saying, "If params is equal to any line in `inventory.txt` then it's valid, otherwise it's invalid"?

Comment: yup, if in inventory i have the line "c1r1s1" and the param is "c1r1s1" so it's valid @TomLord

Comment: But i just wanna know which is the best way to do it in ruby, because i can create a inventory.txt and read it, for after check line by line

Comment: @Bart why do you want to have an external text file? You can just put the valid inputs in your code, e.g. in an array.

Comment: What is a "list of variables"? What you mean by "creating a list of variables"? How does "creating a list of variables" relate to solving your problem? For example, in your code snippet, there are two variables: `min_length` and `max_length`. Or three if you count `params`, which is technically a parameter binding but behaves like a local variable. How does having a list of `min_length`, `max_length`, and `params` solve your problem? If you want an array of variable names, you can call `local_variables` which will return `[:max_length, :min_length, :params]`, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the requirements of your question:

> If params is equal to any line in `inventory.txt` then it's valid, otherwise it's invalid

You can do this:

```
def parseParams(params)
  File.read('inventory.txt').split("\n").include?(params)
end
```

Comment: It is the only way for do it in ruby?

Comment: I mean, ruby does not have some gem or similar for this?

Comment: I think using a third party library for one line of code is a bit overkill :D

Comment: There are probably many ways of solving your problem. For example, using a database, a YAML file, a regex, an Array, ...... But I answered the question that was asked. If you're looking for a broader answer to a wider question about how to solve it, then consider re-framing how the question is asked.

Comment: Okay, it's my bad, you know how to do it using a Database?, can you explain me this method? please

Comment: I don't know whether I'd advise using a database without more context (a simple text file is certainly much simpler, especially if you're writing this as a standalone script; not in the context of a bigger application??). But the idea would simply be: Have all valid inputs in a database table, say, `inventory_items`, and then check if `params` is in the table.

Comment: But I don't think the comments section of a stackoverflow post if the right place to explain "how do I set up a database?". There are numerous resources available for that, if it's something you wish to explore.

Comment: Could be simplified to `readlines` or even `foreach` which would avoid the Array creation all together. Also would recommend against camelCase. (Yes I know it is how the OP wrote it)